# SlideUp and location.href

Tags: jquery, location, hyperlink, slideup

I have a menu with several options. When I select one, I make a slideDown over a hidden div to show the content of it. So far so good, but when I click on another option, I don´t manage the slideUp of the same div to link to another one.

I put my function, with delay() I manage the slideUp but not the link, and without delay() the link works but does not slide...

```
irSobre function () {
        $ ('# scrollbar2'). slideUp ('slow');
        delay (). location.href = "sobre.html";
}
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use delay with a non jquery function.  Try:

```
$('# scrollbar2').slideUp ('slow');
setTimeout(function() { location.href = "sobre.html" }, 500);
```

Where 500 is the number of milliseconds to wait before redirecting.

Comment: you can't use `.delay()` on an object that does not return a `promise()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Setting the Timeout works properly. I´ll take into account your comment about the delay() for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `complete` argument of slideUp to fire your link after the slideUp is finished:

```
$('# scrollbar2').slideUp ('slow', function() {
    location.href = "sobre.html";
});
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Answer (score 0):

Use slideUp's callback function.

```
$('#scrollbar2').slideUp('slow', function(){
    location.href = "sobre.html";
});
```